# Can you construct a railway to Toulon through Marseille? (Paris Connection)

Tags: paris-connection

A round in Paris Connection will end, when someone constructs a route to Marseille.

If player A has enough pawns to construct a route also to Toulon, can he/she also make a route to Toulon on the same turn as he/she places a marker on Marseille? (see the attached picture).

[image: Route to Toulon through Marseille in Paris Connection]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1355526/game-end-really-immediately) response on BoardGameGeeks, immediately means after you are done completing the action that causes the game to end. This is a poor wording then in the game rules, and it should say instead of 'immediately' "at the end of the current turn", or something similar.